# Install Samba 4.4 on Centos 6

Tags: centos, yum, samba

I am running Centos 6.8 and would like to install a higher version of Samba. I am already running Samba, but I think I need some of the newer features (like Spotlight support).

Normally I try to install software via `yum`, and, if possible I would like to do the same for Samba.

- is there a Yum Repo I can use to do this?
- if not, would installing from RPM or Source still use my existing configuration?

I am aware of Samba+, but it’s very expensive for my own needs.

Comment: what is your current samba version ?

Comment: @AliGolestan Version 3.6.23-36.el6_8

Comment: have you tried yum update ?

Comment: Yup. `No Packages marked for Update`

Answer (score 0):

you can directly download any version of Samba from the official site . https://download.samba.org/pub/samba/stable/

you may add EPEL repository too, which provides 100% high quality add-on software packages for Linux distributions. Use below links to add EPEL repository based on your Centos OS versions:

- CentOS 6 32-Bit:

`#wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

`#rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

- CentOS 6 64-Bit:

`#wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

`# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

keep me updated about the result please.

Comment: I have added the repo and tried `yum update samba` again, but there are still no packages marked for Update.

Comment: please try downloading from official site and see if it installs the latest package

Comment: From source? I was hoping to do that via yum or an rpm. In the past I have had issues installing from source while there is an existing yum installation. Would my current configuration still work?

Comment: there is a chance if you install from source your current samba configuration get replaced.
please copy a backup of your current samba configuration then install from source

Comment: It is never recommended to do a compilation of any software on a RHEL system. This is prone to error, mistakes, and possible OS degradation. if you truly need newer packages, please download the source RPM and rebuild it with the version you need using mock.

Comment: @Sokel I am reluctant to build from source, so your comment is interesting. I’d never heard of Mock, but I have since looked it up. Where would I get the appropriate source RPM?

Comment: @Manngo you can get the Mock rpm from EPEL that i've mentioned earlier

Comment: this link will be usefull for you https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/05/11/building-rpm-packages-with-mock/

Comment: @Manngo http://vault.centos.org/6.8/updates/Source/SPackages/ - Please go here for the source packages. You'll need to find the samba4 package and rebuild that for 4.4, as CentOS 6 gives a 'samba' and 'samba4' package.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 6.x provides `samba4` packages with (currently, as of the time of writing this) version `4.2.10`:

`# yum info samba4
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
2111 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Available Packages
Name        : samba4
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 4.2.10
Release     : 15.el6
Size        : 428 k
Repo        : centos6
Summary     : Server and Client software to interoperate with Windows machines
URL         : http://www.samba.org/
License     : GPLv3+ and LGPLv3+
Description : Samba is the standard Windows interoperability suite of programs for Linux and Unix.`

Is 4.2 new enough for your needs?  It's certainly a lot newer than 3.6.x as the default samba version which comes with CentOS 6...  :)

You'll probably also want `samba4-winbind` and some more, but these may be installed as dependencies of this package anyhow.  Check the output of `yum search samba4` for other related packages!